# What video editor should I use for this or what style of video is this called?

Tags: video-editor, animation, software-recommendation

I really like this explainer video put together on Bukowskis:

It's simple with a lot of still images and minimal animations.

Does anyone know what video editing program I can use to make this kind of video? And does this style of video have a name - so I can look for tutorials on making some of these?

Comment: Almost certainly After Effects.  Start by playing with https://www.videocopilot.net/basic/ and go on from there. Just because it looks simple doesn't mean it was made with simple software!